# PHP weirdness extending IMagick class

Tags: php, imagemagick

This is a really weird one.  I have some code that is happily working on version 2.1.1RC1 of the php5-imagick module.  It's basically just a class I wrote that extends the *Imagick* class and manages images stored in a database.

Since upgrading to version 3.0.0RC1 (thankfully only on my dev box) things have gone to hell.  It seems that object members are writeable but are NOT readable.  Take the following sample code:

```
class db_image extends IMagick {

private $data;

function __construct( $id = null ){
    parent::__construct();

    $this->data = 'some plain text';

    echo $this->data;
}
```

This will output absolutely NOTHING.  My debugger indicates that the contents of *$this->data* are the correct string value, but I am unable to read the value back out of the member variable.

Seriously.  WTF?  Does anyone know what is causing this or has seen it before?  I don't even know how to replicate this behaviour in my own classes.

Comment: Pure speculation, but perhaps the new `IMagick` class has its own `private $data` member, which prevents you from overriding it. Do other variable names work as expected?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't matter what the member variable name is.  Call it $sdfhjsdfhlsdf and it will have the same result.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same problem and filed a bug report: http://pecl.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=21229

it seems to be fixed in svn now - but haven't tried yet. Also these types of bugs don't seem to be that exotic: http://pecl.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=15960&edit=2

Answer (score 1):

It indeed seems to be a bug in the imagick library as lifeofguenter pointed out. I have encountered this problem with imagick-3.0.1 and also imagick-3.0.0 - I have solved the problem for myself by downgrading to imagick-2.3.0:

```
# pecl uninstall imagick
# pecl install imagick-2.3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

well, i don't know the IMagick class, but propably it does en exit or die or something in it's constructor, so simply test if the following works:

```
class db_image extends IMagick
{
    private $data;

    function __construct( $id = null )
    {
        $this->data = 'some plain text';
        echo $this->data;

        parent::__construct();
    }
}

new db_image;
```

Comment: Great idea.  But unfortunately it still does the same thing.  Thanks though.

Comment: well, then this sounds like a very uncommon problem.. ^^